# Cannot connect from AWS Athena to Oracle Cloud Infrastructure

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

We are able to connect from Athena to an On Premises Oracle database just fine but our source systems are in the process of migrating to the cloud.

For some reason we are unable to get Athena to connect to OCI (Oracle Cloud Infrastructure).

In our data sources I’m currently getting this error:

> Failed to invoke lambda function due to com.amazonaws.services.lambda.invoke.LambdaFunctionException: Unable to execute HTTP request: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target. A small snippet of the error below:

[image: Error In Athena]

The main difference between our on-premise and cloud connection is that we are using an Oracle Wallet  for the certificates. This wallet (.zip file) is made available to the Lambda function by using a Lambda Function Layer.

We used AWS documentation as a guide: [Implementing mutual TLS for Java-based AWS Lambda functions | AWS Compute Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/implementing-mutual-tls-for-java-based-aws-lambda-functions/)

In our Lambda function we have included the following:

```
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS-Djavax.net.debug=all -Djavax.net.debug=ssl,handshake -Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake:verbose:keymanager:trustmanager -Djavax.net.debug=ssl:record:plaintext -Doracle.net.tns_admin=/opt -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=JKS -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/opt/truststore.jks
```

Has anybody managed to connect successfully to OCI from Athena using a wallet?